# How to make a dynamic frequency histogram from user input

Tags: java, arrays, swing, applet, histogram

```
 Object fileButton = null;
 if("Analyze Text File".equals(command)) {
   JFileChooser filechooser;
   JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
int returnVal = filechooser.showOpenDialog(getParent());
   if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
       File file = filechooser.getSelectedFile();
       String Stext = (String) readFileAsString(file);           //String text = textInput.getText();
       Map<Integer, Integer> counts = getCounts(text);
       int width = counts.size() * BAR_WIDTH;
       int max = maxCount(counts);
       int height = max * INCREMENT + 100;
       int horizon = height - 25;
       HistogramPanel panel = new HistogramPanel(width, counts, height, horizon);
       //panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2));
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
```

i am creating a java applet where it counts the frequency/occurence of X words, i have worked out how to do the array to work out the frequency depending on what the user inputs, i need to now create a bar chart that adapts to whatever the user inputs, i have wrote up a code for my bar chart but i dont know how to connect it to my array code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
 import java.awt.GridLayout;
 import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.awt.Dimension;
 import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Map;

 import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class assignment_work extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

JTextArea textInput;     // User Input.
JLabel wordCountLabel;   // To display number of words.
JLabel meanLabel; // To display the mean.

public void init() {

  // This code from here is the customisation of the Applet, this includes background colour, text      colour, text back ground colour, labels and buttons 

  setBackground(Color.black);
   getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);

   textInput = new JTextArea();
   textInput.setWrapStyleWord(true);

   JPanel ui = new JPanel();
   ui.setLayout(Layout(-1));

   /* Creating Analyze and Reset buttons */

   JButton chartButton = new JButton("Bar Chart");
   chartButton.addActionListener(this);
   ui.add(chartButton);

   JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout())
   //panel.add(chartButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

   /* Labels telling the user what to do or what the program is outputting */

   wordCountLabel.setBackground(Color.black);
   wordCountLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
   wordCountLabel.setOpaque(true);

   meanLabel.setBackground(Color.white);
   meanLabel.setForeground(Color.black);
   meanLabel.setOpaque(true);

watermark.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
watermark.setBackground(Color.darkGray);

   /* Border for Applet. */

   getContentPane().setLayout( new BorderLayout());
   getContentPane().add(ui, BorderLayout.CENTER);

   /* Scroll bar for the text area where the user will input the text they wish to analyse. */

   JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane( textInput );
   getContentPane().add(scroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   getContentPane().add(ui, BorderLayout.NORTH);

  } 


class CustomCanvas extends Canvas {
public CustomCanvas() {
    setBackground(Color.darkGray);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
  }

public void paint(Graphics g) {
int x [] = {20,20,10,10,40,40,30,30};
int y [] = {40,20,20,10,10,20,20,40};
int n = 8;
g.setColor(Color.black);
g.fillPolygon(x,y,n);

int wpoint [] = {45,65,85,75,70,60,55};
int zpoint [] = {40,10,40,40,30,30,40};
int npoint = 7;
g.setColor(Color.black);
g.fillPolygon(wpoint,zpoint,npoint);

int a [] = {60,65,70};
int b [] = {25,20,25};
int npoints = 3;
g.setColor(Color.darkGray);
g.fillPolygon(a,b,npoints);
}
}

private int maxCount(Map<Integer, Integer> counts) {
   counts.values()) {
        if (num > max) {
            max = num;
        }
    }
    return max;
}

public class Panel extends JPanel {

    int width;
    Map<Integer> count;

    public Histogram(int width, Map<Integer, Integer> counts, int horizon) {
        this.width = width;
        this.dimHeight = dimHeight;
        this.horizon = horizon;
    }


    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int x = 10;
        for (Map.Entry<Int> entry : counts.entrySet()) {
            int height = entry.getValue() * INCREMENT;
            int y = horizon - height;
            g.drawString(entry.getValue() + " Frequency", x, y -2);
            x += BAR_WIDTH;
        }
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(width, dimHeight);
    }
    }

    public static Map<Int> getCounts(String Input) {
    Map<Integer> map = new HashMap<Int>();
    String[] array = Input.split("[\\s.,;:!?()");

    for (String array) {
        Int size;
        if (!map(size)) {
            map.put(size, 1);
        } else {
            map.put(map.get(size) + 1);
        }
    }
    return;
    }

   // Text analysis end
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
    if (command.equals("commands")) {
   {
    final graph<Int> Lengths = new graph<Int>();
    String array = Input.Text().split(");
     for (int i = 10; i < array.length; i) {
    final int Length = array[0].length();
    if( Length.Set().container(Length ) ) {
        Integer currentNumberOfOccurences = wordLengths.get(wordLength);
        currentNumberOfOccurences;
        wordLengths.put(wordLength, currentNumberOfOccurences);

    }
    wordLengths.put(wordLength, 1);
    }
    double total =10;
    double total = 10;
    for (final Int length : Lengths.Set()) {
    final Int occurrences = Lengths.get(length);
    Length = tLength + (length * occurrencers );
    totalOccurrences += occurrences;
    }
    final mean = aLength / lOccurrences;
    aLabel.Text("mean word length is: " + (eLength / wOccurrences) );  
   // System.out.println("mean word length is: " + (total / length) );
   }
  String array = textInput.getText().split(" ");
   int maxWordLength = 0;
    wordLength = array[i].length();
    if (wordLength > maxWordLength) {
        maxWordLength = wordLength; 

    }

    int[] intArray = new int[maxWordLength + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    intArray[array[i].length()]++;
     }
    for (int i = 1; i < intArray.length; i++) {
    out.printf("%d word(s) of length %d<br>", intArray[i], i)
    }
   else if (command.equals("Reset")) {
     textInput.setText("");
    textInput.requestFocus();
  }

    Object chartButton = null;
    if (e.getSource() == chartButton) { 
   String text = textInput.getText();
   HistogramPanel panel = new HistogramPanel(width, counts, height, horizon);
   //panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2));
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);

   }
  };

   }
```

---

### Update

Using JFileCHooser

```
private String readFileAsString(String filePath) throws IOException {
    StringBuffer fileData = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader(filePath));
    char[] buf = new char[1024];
    int numRead=0;
    while((numRead=reader.read(buf)) != -1){
        String readData = String.valueOf(buf, 0, numRead);
        fileData.append(readData);
    }
    reader.close();
    return fileData.toString();
}
```

Comment: What's not working about it?

Comment: The bar chart works fine as does the array code, i need to know how to connect them both so that when the user inputs a sentence, it automatically creates a bar chart from the sentence entered with the x axis being the word length and the y axis being the frequency

Comment: So are you saying that everything works perfectly fine when you give static values? Now you want to make it dynamic?

Comment: yes, ill give an example, if the user inputs 'i say by the way' the x axis will be from 1-3 because there is 1 word of length 1, 1 of length 2, 3 of length 3, whereas if the user input hello i am human, the x axis should automatically change to 1-5, hope that makes sense, sorry im new to java :/

Comment: Hi, sorry just wondering if you could give me any pointers? @peeskillet

Comment: Maybe forget trying to make a dynamic number of columns and just stick to a number like 11. 1 - 10 and higher than than 10. Just draw nothing for the ones that are 0. Seems to more sense that way. Either that or pop up a new dialog every time the user inputs something. That way you can have a dynamic size on popup. Otherwise, I'd stick to the same size and have a set number of rows.

Comment: I have to make a dynamic number of columns, this is apart of an university assignment and it says 'The visual appearance of the bar chart scales in an intelligent manner depending on user input', will it all be created within the dynamic class or will i have to use any others?

Comment: Then go with the popup dialog

Comment: If you professor asks why you did it that way, tell him because it looks ugly if you were to have a bunch of empty space or if you made the bars fatter dynamically. Which is true. I doubt there is a requirement to keep everything in the same frame is there?

Comment: Great shall try that now

Comment: No, there is no requirement to keep it in the same frame, there is a bar chart button which the user will click and it will bring a pop up window with the bar chart, i am stuck on how to start this, i have the code for the bar chart and the analysis code above :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you want to do to create the dynamic size from the input.

- You need to get the number of entries in the map, then multiply it by whatever you want the width of each bar to be.
- You need to get the highest value in the map and multiply that by you increment (to draw) amount and create the height from that.
- You create a new JPanel with dimension based on the height and width from the previous two points.
- Iterate through the map the draw the bars.

I do the things above in the `actionPerformed` of a button and I add the `JPanel` to a `JOptionPane`. Let me know if you need clarification on anything.

[image]

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Histogram {

    private static final int BAR_WIDTH = 50;
    private static final int INCREMENT = 10;

    public Histogram() {
        final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 40);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        JButton go = new JButton("Histogram-me!");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(go, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        go.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String text = textArea.getText();
                Map<Integer, Integer> counts = getCounts(text);
                int width = counts.size() * BAR_WIDTH;
                int max = maxCount(counts);
                int height = max * INCREMENT + 100;
                int horizon = height - 25;
                HistogramPanel panel = new HistogramPanel(width, counts, height, horizon);
                //panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2));
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
            }
        });
    }

    private int maxCount(Map<Integer, Integer> counts) {
        int max = 0;
        for (Integer num : counts.values()) {
            if (num > max) {
                max = num;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }

    public class HistogramPanel extends JPanel {

        int width;
        int dimHeight;
        int horizon;
        Map<Integer, Integer> counts;

        public HistogramPanel(int width, Map<Integer, Integer> counts, int dimHeight, int horizon) {
            this.width = width;
            this.counts = counts;
            this.dimHeight = dimHeight;
            this.horizon = horizon;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            int x = 10;
            for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : counts.entrySet()) {
                int height = entry.getValue() * INCREMENT;
                int y = horizon - height;
                g.fillRect(x, y, BAR_WIDTH - 10, height);
                g.drawString(entry.getKey() + " chars", x, horizon + 10);
                g.drawString(entry.getValue() + " times", x, y -2);
                x += BAR_WIDTH;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(width, dimHeight);
        }
    }

    public static Map<Integer, Integer> getCounts(String input) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        String[] array = input.split("[\\s.,;:!?(){}]+");

        for (String s : array) {
            Integer size = s.length();
            if (!map.containsKey(size)) {
                map.put(size, 1);
            } else {
                map.put(size, map.get(size) + 1);
            }
        }
        return map;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Histogram histogram = new Histogram();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried to implement this into my code, i have done most but am getting an error while adding code to my bar chart button, i have edited the code above for u to see..

Comment: 1) You're naming the new panel the same name as your class. Change it to `HistogramPanel` that way it was. Same with the constructor. 2) You already have an `actionPerformed` defined in your class. You can't have two. 3) keep the code a `Map` dont change to `HashMap`. You will see the error. That's all the errors I'm getting.

Comment: And you don't need the `main` method for the applet.

Comment: I got rid of your `actionPerformed`, got rid of the `main` and made the fixes I mentioned, and it works.

Comment: If you need your `actionPerformed`, put a `if (e.getSource() == chartButton) { do my code }` inside of the `actionPerformed` you already have and get rid of my `actionPerformed`

Comment: im still getting a error on line 51: 'HistogramPanel panel = new HistogramPanel(width, counts, height, horizon);' it says cannot find symbol. iv gotten rid of the main and actionPerformed, i havent linked the button to the code, i will once i get back no errors

Comment: Sorry but I don't get that error after making _all_ the fixes I mentioned.

Comment: Do you know how to use a constructor? That's your problem. Also you havent changed the `HashMap` like I said. Ream my comments again.

Comment: You're trying to create a `HistogramPanel` but no such class exists in your code.

Comment: And don't just get rid of the `main` method signature, get rid of everything. You don't need it.

Comment: cool, ill try ti change all those and ill post back if i have anymore problems, sorry if i dont get it right away, i havent been doing java long, and thank you for your help, i do appreciate it :)

Comment: hi sorry to bother you again, i am still having problems with the histogram, i have managed to get it to compile without any errors in my code but it isnt popping up the histogram window when i click the bar chart button even though my code is connected to the bar chart button? if i post my code is it possible you can help me out?

Comment: I saw your new posted question, and your code look even crazier than the last time I saw it. I didn't even want to look at it. That's just being honest. Try and clean it up and take out what you don't need, format it, and you have to at least have an idea where the problem is if you're going to post a wall of code. No one want to debug code that they have no idea of where the problem is.

Comment: i have cleaned up the code and i think the problem lays where i am trying to connect your histogram code to my barchart button, i will edited the post above now for you to see if thats ok?

Comment: Yeah I'll look at it. So the only problem is getting the histogram to show right?

Comment: yes i have connected my text field to your code so i dont need that extra panel for the text, im assuming its just the way iv tried to connect my bar chart button, unless theres something else iv done wrong. i have edited the code above with my new code..

Comment: It's a very simple explanation. The problem is in your `actionPerformed`. You're trying to compare the source of the `ActionEvent` to something that is not (not even your button). You did it right with the other buttons by comparing the `actionCommand`. Just change `if (e.getSource() == chartButton)` to `if ("Bar Chart".equals(command)) {`. It works for me when I do that.

Comment: You may want to make the `BAR_WIDTH` smaller though to accomodate for more frequencies. Just 6 almost takes up the whole screen.

Comment: Great!! i thought i was going wrong somewhere in my action performed, i will remember this for next time, thank you very much for your help, i will change the bar width according to my assignment criteria, one last question, if i was to now select a text file and give the analysed results in this same histogram will using JFileChooser be the best way of going about it?

Comment: Do you know how to read a file? It seems you know how to get the frequencies. You can just read the file into one string, using `StringBuilder` and just pass the String to my method. The `actionPerformed` I used is the simplest way to get the width and height for the histogram. If you don't know how to use a `JFileChooser` look at the tutorial.

Comment: I just did it in 20 lines. Work it out, if you need help with something I'll try and help you out.

Comment: Looks right, Print out the string see if it comes out right. Also what you probably want to do is take in a `File` insstead of a `String filePath` The `JFileChooser` will return a `File` with `chooser.getSelectedFile()`. Then you can `String = readFileAsString(file);` Then just do exactly the same as in the `if ("Bar Chart".equals(command))` but use `if ("Analyze Text File".equals(command)).`

Comment: You can just use `String line; while((line = reader.readLine()) !- null) { stringBuilder.append(line); } return stringBuilder.toString();` Seems easier.

Comment: will i add that to the code i posted above or is this a seperate code that i will add after the jfilechooser has returned the file with chooser.getSelectedFile()

Comment: It's a method. Just keep it as a method, but have it take in a `File` as an argument, instead of a String. The just `File file = chooser.getSelectedFile(); String text = readFileAsString(file);`

Comment: See [How to use FileChoosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) if you don't know the proper way.

Comment: something like that above? i put it on top of the old code, i don't know how to post it as an update :/

Comment: 1) You haven't initialized the `JFileChooser` so you will get a `NullPointerException` 2) `Object String = readFileAsString(file);` should be `String Stext = readFileAsString(file);` 3) `getCounts(file);` should be `getCounts(text);`. `getCounts` takes a String argument not a File. I hope you didn't change it

Comment: 4) `FileChooserDemo.this` is not your class. You will get an error. Don't just copy and paste code and expect it to work. Learn how to actually use it.

Comment: i have changed it, the only error i am getting now is on the:
 Map<Integer, Integer> counts = getCounts(text);
specifically on the (text) area

Comment: the variable right above it is:
String Stext = (String) readFileAsString(file);
will the (file) for this have to match the (text) for the Map line?

Comment: So then why are you passing `text` when the String variable is `Stext`. This is very basic Java

Comment: oh the Stext, i just realised

Comment: ok now because i changed the (parent) of line to (getParent()); :
int returnVal = filechooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
i am getting a error on the filechooser on lines:
 File file = filechooser.getSelectedFile();
int returnVal = filechooser.showOpenDialog(parent);

Comment: Just pass `null` to it

Comment: i have:
  JFileChooser filechooser = null;
right? compiles fine but when i click the Analyze from text button i get a load of errors

Comment: i have but still giving error on file chooser for both lines, its giving me a suggestion saying initialize variable when hovering over file chooser but when i do initialize it changes the JFileChooser filechooser = null

Comment: You had it right the first time. Sorry but I can't help you any further. All this stuff your asking is too basic. You should already know this stuff. You need to figure it out for yourself and learn something