# How to write a method that prints out a histogram?

Tags: java, hashmap, histogram

I have to write this program for lab. I have to basically illustrate exactly what a hashmap is (keys and values) and the basic operations of declaration, .add(), .get(), and how to get the keys and values from the map. You will then apply this to the frequency histogram problem using the woodchucks.txt input file. I've done all this but I'm stuck on how to write my method that prints the histogram. Can someone please help me out?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Lab8
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
    HashMap<String,Integer> histogram = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    String word;
    while ( (word = infile.ready()) != null )
    {
        if(histogram.get(word)==null)
            histogram.put(word,1);
        else
            histogram.put(word, histogram.get(word)+1);

    }   
             // YOUR CODE HERE

    infile.close();
    printHistogram( histogram );

} // END MAIN
// YOU FILL IN THIS METHOD
// READ PROBLEM SPECIFICATION TO SEE WHAT IS THE 80% vs 100% CREDIT SOLUTION

private static void printHistogram( HashMap<String,Integer> hm )
{

    // YOU CODE HERE
}
} // END LAB8 CLASS
```

Would I print the histogram like this?

```
for ( int i = 0; i < histogram.length; i++ )
         {
         output += "\n" + i + "\t" + histogram[ i ] + "\t";

         for ( int j = 1; j <= histogram[ i ]; j++ )
```

Comment: Oh sorry, no. My teacher made those comments where he wanted us to add the code. As you can see that is where I have to make the method. Can you just give me some hints as to how to approach it... I believe I have to use a for loop?

Comment: Try it out first... Seems like it is your class assignment!

Comment: If you can see in the while loop I've already added code there and finished that. It is just the private method Im stuck on

Comment: You need to give it a try yourself, then come back and ask questions if you get stuck.

Comment: Okay let me give it a shot... I'll edit the question

Comment: what is your problem exactly? where did you stuck?

Comment: I got stuck on how to write the private method on the bottom

Comment: @Ayoshna in which bit, and what you need to be there?  simple word count or something else

Comment: I need to print the histogram by pulling the keys (words) out into an array or ArrayList, sort the array then loop thru the sorted keys and use each key in a .get(word) to produce the freq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and this is the answer...

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Lab8
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
    HashMap<String,Integer> histogram = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    String word;
    while ((infile.ready()))
    {
        word = infile.readLine();
        if(histogram.get(word)== null) //if the word your currently on is not duplicated
        {
            histogram.put(word,1);
        }
        else
        {
            histogram.put(word, histogram.get(word)+1);
        }
    }   
             // YOUR CODE HERE

    infile.close();
    printHistogram( histogram );

} // END MAIN
// YOU FILL IN THIS METHOD
// READ PROBLEM SPECIFICATION TO SEE WHAT IS THE 80% vs 100% CREDIT SOLUTION

private static void printHistogram( HashMap<String,Integer> hm )
{
    List <String> keys = new ArrayList<String> (hm.keySet());   
    Collections.sort(keys);
    for (String key: keys) 
    {
        System.out.println(key + "\t"  + hm.get(key));

    }
} 
}// END LAB8 CLASS
```

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22075683/2587435). It may help also.

Answer (score 0):

So if i'll be doing this, i would start from creating two classes, one where i could hold word and number occurrences such as my `HistogramItem`

```
public class HistogramItem implements Comparable<HistogramItem> {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "HistogramItem [word=" + word + ", occurence=" + occurence
                    + "]";
        }

        public int getOccurence() {
            return occurence;
        }

        public void updateOccurence() {
            this.occurence++;
        }

        public String getWord() {
            return word;
        }

        public HistogramItem(String word) {
            super();
            this.word = word;
        }

        private final String word;
        private int occurence = 0;

        @Override
        public int compareTo(HistogramItem o) {

            if (occurence == o.occurence) {
                return word.compareTo(o.word);
            }
            return o.occurence-occurence;
        }

    }
```

and other one which will be my actual histogram

```
public class Histogram {
        private Map<String, HistogramItem> map = new HashMap<>();
        private List<HistogramItem> list = new ArrayList<>();

        public void addWord(String word) {
            HistogramItem item = map.get(word);
            if (item == null) {
                item = new HistogramItem(word);
                map.put(word, item);
                list.add(item);
            }
            item.updateOccurence();
        }

        public List<HistogramItem> getList() {
            Collections.sort(list);
            return list;
        }

    }
```

i'm using two collections, hashmap, because search for entry is much quicker than in list, but list is much easier to sort, list can be created and sorted when requested

How this fits your original excercise?  Simple

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
    Histogram histogram = new Histogram();
    String word;
    while ( (word = infile.ready()) != null )
    {
       histogram.addWord(w);

    }   
             // YOUR CODE HERE

    infile.close();

//   Below line prints histogram, can be placed in printHistogram method
for (HistogramItem item : histogram.getList()) {
            System.out.println(item.toString());
        }

} // END MAIN
```