# Counting occurrences inside an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have gone back, as advised, and started looking at some code i wrong months ago and have been attempting to update it so as it will be more efficient.

All i want is for my method to return a new array that has the occurrences in it.

for example :   `count({2,4,0,7,4,2,1,0})` `returns {2,1,2,0,2,0,0,1}`

so far my method for this is this and just for the record and i guess viewers sake, the array i'm working with is this.

```
18  29  23  35  23  28  36  27  16  21  33  21  18  33  16  6  19  22  9  26  28  16  19  14  18  12  17  28
```

this is my count class

```
public int[] count(Integer[] nums)
{
    Integer[] numOccur = new Integer[nums.length]; //new array that will be returned with the occurances

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i) //goes through the array for nums.length times.
    {
        Integer count = nums[i]; //assigns count to nums[i]
        numOccur[count]++;         //ERROR
        System.out.println(numOccur[i]); //testing to see if i'm printing the right value
    }

    return numOccur;
}
```

I'm getting a

```
at WeatherSrv.count(WeatherSrv.java:94)
    at WeatherDrv.main(WeatherDrv.java:55)
Java Result: 1
```

I know the problem is happening in my assignment of the new elements insides my array[] numOccur, is it just because of my assignment? I just want to know if i'm heading in the right direction.

In my previous version of this i was only using a switch statement, no arrays so this is a little different.

EDIT 1: I Should have posted my main method that i'm using this with!

`weather.count(res)` where res is the array i posted at the top above my class

/*THIS IS MY FIRST POST EVERY - if anyone has any tips about wording a better question please dont hesitate, i would like the most clear, not given answer

Comment: Maybe you only have to cast count i mean you should do this:  numOccur[ (int)count ]++;

Comment: is this because its an Integer and i need it as an int? in anycase, i still got the same error as before

Comment: It should be `count( new int [] {2,4,0,7,4,2,1,0} )`, since method `count` takes an array of `int` as parameter

Comment: i'm already passing it an array, no need to initialize a new one inside the method

Comment: Using a `HashMap` would be better suited for this.

Comment: HashMap i looked this up, mind elaberating?

Comment: Any time you hear "Count the number of" anything, think of a `HashMap`, which is an implementation of a `HashTable`.  Key/value pairs so that you map a number to the number of occurrences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could definitly get your current implementation working with what @Elliott Frisch suggested, but you could also go a different route and use a `HashMap`.

Here is a working solution using a `HashMap`, it has the added benefit of not needing to iterate over a potentially large number of empty indexes, since only numbers that exist in the initial array will have a value in the `HashMap`.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class CountOccur
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Integer[] arr = new Integer[]{2,4,0,7,4,2,1,0};
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> countMap = count(arr);

    for (Integer key : countMap.keySet()) {
      System.out.println(key + " count: " + countMap.get(key));
   }

  }

  public static HashMap<Integer, Integer> count(Integer[] nums)
  { 
      HashMap<Integer, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

      for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i)
      {
          Integer count = countMap.get(nums[i]); 
          if (count  == null){
            //first occurrence, enter a value of 1 for count
            countMap.put(nums[i], 1);
          }
          else{
            //already in the HashMap, increment the count
            countMap.put(nums[i], count + 1);
          }

      }

      return countMap;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
0 count: 2
1 count: 1
2 count: 2
4 count: 2
7 count: 1
```

To address the downside to your original approach,  imagine the input: `{1,1000000}`. You would need an array with a size of 1000001, and in order to process the returned array you would need to iterate over all one million and one indexes, with all of them empty except for two.

Comment: in the future, could this be considered a more efficient choice? and where would a public static HashMap go? inside my service class or the main class?

Comment: Only other problem i have with this is it works brilliantly but now i have no count method at all?

Comment: I'm just thinking of how i would test this. You know? i have my Service class with all my methods, count being included in there, and i have a seperate main method that i want to test this out with. For instance something like,  count({4,4,4,0,0,0,0,2}) returns {0 count: 3, 2 count: 1, etc}

Comment: ohhhhh wow i see so blind! not used to seeing things like <><> in a method signature. If you don't mind my asking, not trying to 'discuss' but ive seen things like HashMap<><> and Iterator<><> and such, what are these things?

Comment: and if i were to try to instead of passing an array of Integers just say something like obj.count(new Integer{1, 2, 3}) or is that illegal?

Comment: @WilliamMabry the input to `count()` is still `Integer[] nums`, so you can pass in exactly what you could before.  The only thing that changed is the return value.  Note that the correct input though would be `new Integer[]{1, 2, 3}`

Comment: if i wanted to extend this into an histogram i feel like instead of just +1 incrementing could i somehow just do '*'++ or something along those lines? @DanielNugent

Comment: @WilliamMabry I'm not sure what kind UI you would be using for the histogram, but this answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22050158/how-to-make-a-dynamic-frequency-histogram-from-user-input/22075683#22075683

Comment: weather histogram, on 3 days it was 6 degrees "6: ***" No worries though, nothing is required i was just wondering how to further display my data. What you linked me looks really confusing xD thank you though! very much

Answer (score 0):

You need to size the output array based on the maximum value in the input array. You could start with a method to find the maximum value in an array like

```
private static int getMaxValue(Integer[] nums) {
    int max = nums[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
        max = Math.max(max, nums[i]);
    }
    return max;
}
```

Then your method should size its' output array like

```
// You return an `int[]`
int[] numOccur = new int[1+getMaxValue(nums)];
```

Comment: what would this do? i have a method that gets max but i dont see why i would use it here when my length of nums is going to be the same seeing as each element is going to occur at least once since its there

Comment: @WilliamMabry I believe your code counts the occurrences of values `0` to `n`. In your original method, you assumed `n` was the length of the array `nums`. I'm telling you `n` is the `maxValue` of the array `nums`.

Answer (score 0):

when you call this line:

```
Integer[] numOccur = new Integer[nums.length]
```

that means you create a new array with nums.length, so you can get an index between 0 and nums.length-1, but when you assign a value to this array like this `numOccur[count]++;` count is a value of array named nums, count may be bigger than nums.length-1. Your program may point out an Exception of `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: so i would need something like maybe numOccur[count[i]++; in theory?